# Anyone have these 7 cards from The Fortune Teller Board Game by Pressman 1989

Tags: untagged

I found this game (The Fortune Teller by Pressman from 1989) but it's missing 7 cards. I was wondering if someone would share insight of those missing 7 cards and I'll make the missing cards so I can play the game (?) the 1st card is a Titled Card for Change So I would need the other side which lists 6 words from top to bottom. The other 6 cards start with these words....Accomplishment, Affection, Illness, Interference, Materialist and Momentum, with then their other 5 words on that side of their cards. Maybe you could take a photo of the back of the cards with the words and email those or attach them to this message, whatever would be the easiest.

Answer (score 3):

[image][image][image][image]Becky, I have this game. I can send you pictures.

Comment: I would like a copy of the rules that came with this game, if you have them. Thank you!

Comment: To post pictures.  Click the "edit" button.  Then click the picture icon in the edit area toolbar.  That will bring up a dialog box that will allow you to drag&drop or paste an image or a link to an image and the image will appear in your answer.